# Pipeline run arguments with generated option list

Tags: azure-pipelines

When defining a pipeline with parameters, I can specify `values`, a list of allowed values, and they will be presented as a combo-box. But is there a way to either generate the list with code, or read it from somewhere outside the pipeline definition where I can update it with code?

The idea is that the pipeline will be interacting with some other system, and the parameter must match what is available there—e.g. an available artifact ID, a branch or an environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that to update the runtime parameters outside the pipeline definition is not possible. They have to be defined in the YAML file.

But you may you can access this URL: https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas to submit your detailed request for future releases and implementations. The development team is always reviewing these submissions.